# $category->getChildren(); does not work?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-tree

When I am using `$category->getChildren();` and I am getting empty array? I have children categories defined and I can see them via Admin Panel. 
Where should I look for the clue?
thanks

Comment: Have you tried `getChildrenCategories()`? `getChildren()` should return a string with coma seperated ids, not an array at all.

Comment: the source code of 1.9.1.0 says that getChildren() returns array but indeed official document from magento says it is string.... anyway it is empty and getChildrenCategories() also returns empty array....

Comment: should I be looking at catalog_category_entity table...?

Comment: Well, at this point I would try and output the `$category->getData()` via print_r or var_dump and see what's in there for children

Comment: @user3154108 I am getting following after print_r($category->getData()): Array
     (
        [entity_id] => 30
        [entity_type_id] => 3
        [attribute_set_id] => 3
        [parent_id] => 2 ........
      )

Comment: forgot to add that there were no attribute for children....

Comment: Ok, I only got an 1.8.1 version for testing, but with getData() you should have an attribute "children_count" which tells you how many children your Category has. getChildren() gives me a string with ids and getChildrenCategories gives me an array of Category Objects.
It does work in 1.8.1 at least. Can you post Screenshots of categories and maybe source code where you use your $category?

Comment: getData() returns children_count with correct value however getChildren() returns NULL.

Comment: link to the screenshot [link](http://awesomescreenshot.com/image/139732/4fc56e5fc2de58ecb13ec74a4f9d5961)  and the code:  foreach (Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories()  as $category) {
          if ($category->getIsActive()) {
                $categories[] = $category;
            }
        }              when I do inside this loop $category->getChildren() will get NULL and getData() is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found the solution.

my `$category` is of `Varien_Data_Tree_Node` type and
`$category->getChildren()` is `Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection`
the problem was that in the Magento Config, Maximal Depth was set to 1. That is why I was getting empty collection (`Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection`) for each category and children_count was OK. Changing Maximal Depth variable to 2 solved the problem.

Thanks!